# Scroll for checkboxlist doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, scroll, checkboxlist

I have this CheckBoxList :

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList class="checkBoxList" ID="CheckBoxList1"  runat="server"   
        TextAlign="Right" float="right" >
```

and this css:

```
 .checkBoxList {
    direction:rtl;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
    height:200px%;
    overflow-y:scroll 
}
```

But my CheckBoxList doesn't have scroll, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternate method of this is wrap your checkboxlist in to div and make div scrollable 
here is the code

```
<div class="checkBoxList">
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="surver" ID="CheckBoxList1">
// Your Code
</asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

and css is

```
 .checkBoxList {
    direction:rtl;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll
   }
```